# Swift cannot assign value of type [String : SomeProtocol] to type [String : SomeProtocol]

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have some protocol called `SomeProtocol` and few structs that conform to it

```
struct myStruct1: SomeProtocol {}
struct myStruct2: SomeProtocol {}
```

I have the map

```
var myArray = [String : SomeProtocol]()
```

And when I try

```
myArray = ["val1": myStruct1(), "val2": myStruct2()]
```

I got an error:

> Swift cannot assign value of type [String : SomeProtocol] to type
>   [String : SomeProtocol]

Comment: I am running the code in playground using an empty SomeProtocol. I am not getting any error. Can you please check again.

Comment: this happens in one specific project while this code works in other places I already tried clean build and deleting derived data

Comment: Do you perhaps have two definitions of `SomeProtocol` in your project?

Comment: @Hamish it seems that was the problem! Thank you - you can post as an answer. Maybe you can describe why Swift lets to have two different protocols with the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hamish mentioned in comments: 
it happened because there were two definitions of SomeProtocol in the project.

To solve this issue you simply need to rename one of protocols.